Fonts in the react application do not work with the .scss extension
I use Vite with React + SCSS.
And I have fonts.scss where I use all my fonts for project:
@font-face {
    font-family: "JosefinSans";
    src: url("./JosefinSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "JosefinSans";
    src: url("./JosefinSans-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 700;
}

But when I try to import my fonts on different path of my project like this:
@import "./assets/fonts/fonts.scss";
@import "./assets/colors/colors.scss";

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "JosefinSans";
    background-color: $border-light;
}

My fonts are not working. They only work when I compile to .css and use import with a .css file.
I tried checking if it works with .css files, and it does. However, I only want to use .scss in my project.
In the package.json file, I have sass, and I checked if any other .scss code like variables works. Everything works, but the fonts don't work.

You can try using using ~ before the path so vite will resolve the path correctly relative to your project root also make sure that you have the right path so your code would be like this
@font-face {
font-family: "JosefinSans";
src: url("~./assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: 400;
}

